# How do I use the Argon2 algorithm with password_hash?

Tags: php, algorithm, php-password-hash, php-7.2, argon2-ffi

So I heard that PHP 7.2 introduced the new [Argon2 algorithm](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argon2_password_hash). But I'm confused on how I can use it with my existing code. For instance, I have this

```
$password = password_hash('somepassword', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]);
```

Does `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` now use Argon2? What, if anything, do I need to change with `password_verify`? Is bcrypt considered insecure now?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## What is Argon2? Is bcrypt bad now?

Prior to PHP 7.2, the only hashing algorithm `password_hash` used was bcrypt. As of this writing, bcrypt is still considered a strong hash, especially compared to its predecessors, `md5` and `sha1` (both of which are [insecure because they are fast](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)). Argon2 is [simply a costlier algorithm to brute force](https://www.techtic.com/blog/introduction-of-argon2-algorithm-with-PHP-72)

> Argon2i uses data-independent memory access. It is slower because it makes more passes over the memory to protect from trade off attacks. It is highly recommended for password hashing and password-based key derivation.

Bcrypt is still an acceptable hash for passwords. There's no need to switch if you don't want to (as of the 7.2.0 release). Also, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` should only change (per [PHP Internals policy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-notes)) on the next full release (7.3.0 or higher). If you want to ensure you continue with only bcrypt, you can use `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` instead. This is unnecessary, however, as we'll discuss below.

## How do you use Argon2?

First, we'll switch the second argument of `password_hash` over to one of these to constants

- `PASSWORD_ARGON2I` - PHP 7.2.0+
- `PASSWORD_ARGON2ID` - PHP 7.3.0+ (preferred if available, see notes below)

and then we'll need to change our options. bcrypt uses `cost` as the parameter for how many times it iterates over the password (higher cost = longer hashing time). There's different cost factors, however

```
password_hash('somepassword', PASSWORD_ARGON2I, ['memory_cost' => 2048, 'time_cost' => 4, 'threads' => 3]);
```

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-description) we see what these options do

- `memory_cost` - Maximum memory (in kibibytes) that may be used to compute the Argon2 hash (default 1024)
- `time_cost` - Maximum amount of time it may take to compute the Argon2 hash (default 2)
- `threads` - Number of threads to use for computing the Argon2 hash (default 2)

Understand, before you go changing these, that a higher cost here **will slow down your script**. You'll want to run a test on your server to find a setting that works best for you. This is typically by looping over several iterations of a given cost. The [PHP manual gives an example of this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#example-983) if you need one.

Also note that, while bcrypt stores 60 characters, Argon2 can require more than that. You should, ideally, make your password field store 255 characters.

## What do we change in `password_verify`?

The answer here is... nothing. Understand that `password_verify` is smart enough to figure out what algorithm was used and handle it appropriately. As mentioned above, this means that if you are using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, the default can change and not negatively affect you (although you may need to adjust the cost parameters). `password_verify` simply requires an algorithm it supports. If you switch from bcrypt to Argon2, both will verify the same way, as all the necessary data (salt, hash and cost) are stored for you.

```
//Works for both bcrypt and Argon2
if(password_verify($user_password, $stored_hash)) {
    // password validated
}
```

If you want to upgrade the hashes from bcrypt, you can do this when a user successfully logs in (and thus supplied you with the un-hashed password). Simply check if your hash starts with `$2y$` (the bcrypt marker). If it does, pass the supplied password to `password_hash` again, but with the Argon2 arguments, and save it to the password field of the logged-in user.

## What is Argon2ID?

[Introduced in PHP 7.3](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argon2_password_hash_enhancements), Argon2ID makes some improvements over Argon2I as noted in this [Crypto.SE question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48935/why-use-argon2i-or-argon2d-if-argon2id-exists)

> The best tradeoff attack on 1-pass Argon2id is the combined low-storage attack (for the first half of the memory) and the ranking attack (for the second half), which bring together the factor of about 2.1.

Argon2ID works with the same arguments that Argon2I works with.

Comment: It would be useful on this answer to add how to load Argon2 into the PHP runtime modules. You answer implies PHP 7.2 has it by default whereas I can only show on my settings that PHP 7.1 *doesn't*, Cheers

Comment: @Martin There's no module to load. If you're running 7.2.0 or later it's there (`password_hash` is [core PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/password.installation.php)). I am unaware of any backporting options, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Instead of checking what the string starts with, you should probably use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php as *"This function checks to see if the supplied hash implements the algorithm and options provided"*.

Comment: _that a higher cost here will **slow down your script.**_ Does this happens only during the process of `password_hash()` OR `password_verify()` as well?

Comment: @IrfandyJip Both. Remember, `password_verify` takes all the options of the hash and the password to be verified and **generates a new hash**. If the new hash (with the same exact options) matches the old, the password is verified.

Comment: Is it the `memory_cost` and `time_cost` a must have? Or we can just simply do password_hash(`"somepassword" , PASSWORD_ARGON2ID)`?

Comment: @SilverSurfer Costs are not required. If you don't supply values, PHP uses the default

Answer (score 1):

**Only if you use PHP 7.3:**
I've created 2 simple and slim functions to use Argon2ID with PHP:

```
function argon2idHash($plaintext, $password, $encoding = null) {
    $plaintextsecured = hash_hmac("sha256", $plaintext, $password);
    return $encoding == "hex" ? bin2hex(password_hash($plaintextsecured, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID)) : ($encoding == "base64" ? base64_encode(password_hash($plaintextsecured, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID)) : password_hash($plaintextsecured, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID));
}

function argon2idHashVerify($plaintext, $password, $hash, $encoding = null) {
    $plaintextsecured = hash_hmac("sha256", $plaintext, $password);
    return password_verify($plaintextsecured, $encoding == "hex" ? hex2bin($hash) : ($encoding == "base64" ? base64_decode($hash) : $hash)) ? true : false;
}
```

To get an hashed value use (the last parameter is optional, you can choose *hex*, *base64* or nothing) [return => string]:

```
$salt = "LALALA";
argon2idHash($clearvalue, $salt, "hex"); // with encoding
argon2idHash($clearvalue, $salt); // without encoding
```

To verify an hashed value use (parameter $salt must match the salt set at the time of hashing also the same rule applies to encoding if used) [return => bool]:

```
$salt = "LALALA";
argon2idHashVerify($clearvalue, $salt, $hashtoverify, "hex") ? "match" : "dont match"; // with encoding
argon2idHashVerify($clearvalue, $salt, $hashtoverify) ? "match" : "dont match"; // without encoding
```

Finally, if you know PHP you can modify these functions to your liking, but for now it's the best way I know to securely store passwords in databases.

Comment: The function that I created as the only thing transforms the text to be encrypted in sha256-hmac with a password or salt chosen by you, then the standard argon function is used. Mine is an extra step that gives additional security. You now say that argon2 is safe, we will have to see in a few years how much it will be. For the downvote your motivation I do not consider it valid.